# Postgresql replication and replication slot blocking VACUUM

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have a question about replication in PostgresSQL. I am executing a `VACUUM` on a table and I get this information:

> DETAIL:  3263410 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 574

On this website, the point 2 explains the reason why I am getting that information, but I do not know how to fix it.

https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/

The select returns:

```
slot_name       slot_type     temporary  active   xmin   restart_lsn
it_rdbms02      physical         f         f        574     0/302B380
```

I read you can delete the slot with the function `pg_drop_replication_slot('name_slot')` but this will disable my replication?

Answer: Yes, will delete the replication.

Answer (score 1):

I am glad that my article proved helpful.

If your replication is working, that would be a sign that it is not using the replication slot. Check `recovery.conf` on the standby server to verify that.

A replication slot marks a certain WAL position, so that the primary server won't discard any WAL after that position. The reason is that someone, for example a replication standby, will still need the information.

During normal operation, the WAL consumer that uses the replication slot will *advance* it regularly. But if nobody uses it any more, it blocks WAL recycling and `VACUUM` and is a major problem.

If your replication doesn't explicitly use the replication slot in `recovery.conf`, you can safely delete it.

Comment: I do not have any recovery.conf, when i get an error i use to recover the nodes manually. But still getting the row and not updating the xmin. Any idea?

Comment: You cannot have streaming replication without `recovery.conf`. Otherwise, how would the standby know where the primary is? Look **at the standby server**.